# Video not playing

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am using VideoView trying to play video. But when I use this code I have following error:

> Sorry, this video cannot be played

What is wrong here?

```
 VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);   
 String path = "/mnt/sdcard/Video/1345467237098.m4v"
 vv.setVideoPath(path);
```

Comment: Most probably it does not support the .m4v format, or the file path is incorrect. Try playing instead a .3gp file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This format is not supported, please check this url https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html

Answer (score 0):

Th format in which the video is, is not supported by Android. I suggest you convert your video to .mp4 (which is supported).

I hope this helps.